# How to see generated source from an URL page with python script and not anly source?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, url, dynamically-generated

I have some url to parse, and they used some javascript to create it dynamicly. So if i want to parse the result generated page with python... how can i do that ?

Firefox do that well with web developer... so i think it possible ... but i don't know where to start...

Thx for help

lo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this by doing a POST of document.body.innerHTML, after the page is loaded, to a CGI script in Python.

For the parsing, BeautifulSoup is a good choice.

Comment: hmm, as I reread the question, these aren't your pages you're talking about, they're someone else's. this trick might still work if you load the others' pages in iframes.

Comment: I probably do, but don't have time to find it right now... really busy.

Answer (score 0):

I you want generated source you'll need a browser, I don't think you can with only python.